# How does the electoral college give smaller states more of a voice?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

The most popular reason I have heard in favor of the electoral college is that it gives smaller states more of a voice, which I still don’t understand. If the number of electoral votes a state gets is based on its population, how does that benefit smaller states?

Answer (score 6):

See [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_US_electoral_votes_per_popular_vote) for a list of how many votes is required for an electoral vote in different states. Massachusetts for instance have 3.60912 electoral votes per million voter, but North Dakota has 9.66022. This means that a vote in North Dakota is worth about three times as much as a vote in Massachusetts.